# How to insert data into 12*2 array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have following local variables in my class

```
    String A1="a1";
    String A2="a2";
    String A3="a3";
    String B1="b1";
    String B2="b2";
    String B3="b3";
    String B4="b4";
```

And need to insert above `Strings` into `Array[12][2]` in such a way that all A's should link to all B's. i.e.,

`A1,B1
 A1,B2
 A1,B3
 A1,B4
 A2,B1
 .
 .
 .
 A3,B4`

I used following Approach right now to insert data

```
String[][]  array={{A1,B1},{A1,B2},{A1,B3},.....{A3,B4}};
```

Is there any other best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

put the a's and b's into two string arrays, then you can init like so

```
array[i][0] = a[i%3]
array[i][1] = b[i%4]
```

(for i from 0 to 11)